# How to ignore error in 'excludesfile' in Ant if file is not present

Tags: ant

I use

`<zipfileset ..><excludesfile name="D:\SW\abc.h"/>..</zipfileset>`

to exclude this file while zipping

Problem is if this file does not exist, Ant throws error.

Are there any ignore settings?

I have many `<excludesfile>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `excludesfile` element or attribute is intended to specify the name of a file, each line of which is taken to be an exclude pattern. See the documentation for [PatternSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html).

I think you are incorrectly using the attribute to specify the names of files you want to exclude literally, rather than in the named excludes file itself.

One solution would be to list all the files you require to be excluded from your zip in a file (each on a new line) and give the name of this file in the `excludesfile` attribute or element of your `zipfileset`.

Alternatively, you could use a comma or space separated list of the files in the `excludes` attribute. Or you could replace your multiple `excludesfile` elements with multiple `exclude` elements.